# git: Get source so i can compile, not everything?

Tags: git

github has a download button which offers a download for .tar.gz and .zip files. Essentially i want the same thing for the latest branch or of a tag. I dont want to work on the project, i just want to compile it. How do i get the source only of any git repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a shallow clone:

> A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.

---

```
git clone --depth 1 /path/to/repo.git
```

Will result in a Shallow clone of the repo with the current revision only.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git archive`; something like:

```
git archive --format=tar --remote=$REPO $BRANCH | tar xf -
```

This command gets *only* the source tree with no git metadata (i.e., no `.git` subdirectory).  It is also very fast.  The command above writes the source code into the current directory; to write it into a subdirectory add the option `--prefix=subdir/`.